# \ifbeamer@anotherslide and \ifbeamer@localanotherslide in beamerbasedecode.sty

Tags: beamer, macros, conditionals, scoping

At the beginning of the source file `beamerbasedecode.sty` of `beamer` class, two switches are defined:

```
\newif\ifbeamer@anotherslide
\newif\ifbeamer@localanotherslide
```

By reading `beamerbasedecode.sty` and `beamerbaseframe.sty`, I have some knowledge of `\ifbeamer@anotherslide`: In every `frame` environment, `beamer` calls `\beamer@masterdecode`, and `\beamer@masterdecode` would change the switch `\ifbeamer@anotherslide`. While it is true, `beamer` would calls `\beamer@masterdecode` again and again, and at last generates all slides in the frame.

Inside `\beamerbasedecode.sty`, It seems that `\ifbeamer@anotherslide` and `\ifbeamer@localanotherslide` always have the same value:

```
\global\beamer@anotherslidetrue\beamer@localanotherslidetrue
```

The only difference is the `\global` before the first one. But in the main macro `\beamer@masterdecode`, the second one is also made global.

```
\def\beamer@stoptexts{| stop:0| }
{
   \catcode`\|=13
   \catcode`\:=13
   \catcode`\,=13
   \catcode`\.=13
   \catcode`\+=13
   \catcode`\-=13
   \catcode`\(=13
   \catcode`\)=13
   \catcode`\ =13
\gdef\beamer@masterdecode#1{% must be called within a group
\ifnum\catcode`\|=13\edef|{\string|}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\:=13\edef:{\string:}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\,=13\edef,{\string,}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\.=13\edef.{\string.}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\+=13\edef+{\string+}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\-=13\edef-{\string-}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\(=13\edef({\string(}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\)=13\edef){\string)}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\ =13\edef {\string }\fi%
\edef\beamer@@@temp{#1\beamer@stoptexts}%
\beamer@localanotherslidefalse%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\expandafter\beamer@decode\beamer@@@temp%
\ifbeamer@localanotherslide\global\beamer@localanotherslidetrue\fi}%
}%
```

This confuses me: what are the differences between `\ifbeamer@anotherslide` and `\ifbeamer@localanotherslide`? Why we needs `\ifbeamer@localanotherslide`?

Comment: I think it's fair to say this is not really clear, certainly without any notes! It would be easy enough to do some tests but as there is no full suite for `beamer` I'd be extremely wary of altering it in the release version!